# Why is HTMX Download not working But CDN works?

Tags: htmx

https://htmx.org/docs/#installing documentation states :-

1. gives a CDN method <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.8"... Works Well No Problems.
2. when I swap (1 above) out for a downloaded
   https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.8/dist/htmx.min.js
   and reference it with ( script src="/path/to/htmx.min.js"></script )
   I get error in browser no matter which browser I use ?

[image]

3) the go main.go as requested.
func main() {

```
fmt.Println("Hello, World!")

// handler function #1 - returns the index.html template, with film data
h1 := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))
    films := map[string][]Film{ // key is string, value is slice of Film
        "Films": {
            {Title: "The Godfather", Director: "Francis Coppola"},
            {Title: "Star Wars", Director: "George Lucas"},
            {Title: "Casablanca", Director: "Michael Curtiz"},
        },
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, films) // pass films map to template
}

// handler function #2 - returns the template block with the newly added film, as an HTMX response
h2 := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    title := r.PostFormValue("title")
    director := r.PostFormValue("director")
    // htmlStr := fmt.Sprintf("<li class='list-group-item bg-primary text-white'>%s - %s</li>", title, director)
    // tmpl, _ := template.New("t").Parse(htmlStr)
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "film-list-element", Film{Title: title, Director: director})
}

// define handlers
http.HandleFunc("/", h1)
http.HandleFunc("/add-film/", h2)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

}

The index.html // this is the full program htmx.min.js is on the root with main.go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
   <!--  <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.8" integrity="sha384-rgjA7mptc2ETQqXoYC3/zJvkU7K/aP44Y+z7xQuJiVnB/422P/Ak+F/AqFR7E4Wr" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

    <!--  above is commented out to use the below direct referance which does not work ?  -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="htmx.min.js"></script>
    <title>HTMX  Demo</title>
</head>

<body class="container">
<!--
<iframe width="560" height="315" src='https://dbdiagram.io/e/655efcb83be1495787921d3c/655efd923be1495787922e15'> </iframe>
-->
    <div class="row mt-4 g-4">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h1 class="mb-4">Film List</h1>        
            <ul class="list-group fs-5 me-5" id="film-list">
                {{ range .Films }}
                {{ block "film-list-element" .}}
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-primary text-white">{{ .Title }} - {{ .Director }}</li>
                {{ end }}
                {{ end }}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <h1 class="mb-4">Add Film</h1>

            <form hx-post="/add-film/" hx-target="#film-list" hx-swap="beforeend" hx-indicator="#spinner">
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <label for="film-title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="film-title" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="film-director">Director</label>
                    <input type="text" name="director" id="film-director" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm htmx-indicator" id="spinner" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</ht
```

ml>

Comment: You're sure the js file is downloaded raw, not as html source or something? The warning kinda indicates this.

Comment: I just checked = when you navigate to https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.8/dist/htmx.min.js and choose save it's extension is automatically set as JS file. Not HTML source.

Comment: Can you show us the response from htmx file in your browser console?

Comment: No responds from HTMX file it just shows HTML with HTMX not working ( linked to local down loaded file ). But as started if HTMX is directly linked to web linked file it works. same code just different XTMX location.  As my pages need to work off line i need a local copy and not an external dependency if i am to use HTMX.

Comment: Your error "expected expression, got '<'" indicates that your local htmx.min.js file starts with "<" which makes me believe it is some type of different format then javascript code (especially if you're on windows and it probably saved it as source page, not raw file) You can check the network tab and the response content of the htmx.min.js to make sure what the content of this file is.

Comment: A search for "<" in local file  htmx.min.js does not find any instances.  It is saved as a raw file named  htmx.min.js .  Issue still not resolved.

Comment: 1) can you try adding `type="text/javascript"` as see if that works? 2) Can you add your go script, which I assume is handling the static files? Thanks.

Comment: I tried <script type="text/javascript" src="htmx.min.js"></script> but not working.

Comment: I uploaded the go and html to stackoverflow and i rechecked by down loading the latest htmx.min.js. This code works for https source but no for local file. In my project I am web disconnected at all times. p.s bootstrap test will be just CSS later.

Answer (score 0):

You should use go to also handle serving the static files. Something like this should work:

```go
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

Move your js file to `static` folder, and serve it like this:

```html
<script src="static/htmx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward to HTMX Documentation update.

To install an HTMX downloaded copy in go, use the following 3 steps:

1. use go to handle the serving of static files

```js
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

2. Move the `htmx.min.js` into a root/static folder
   https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/releases/download/v1.9.8/htmx.min.js
3. serve in HTML:

```html
script src="static/htmx.min.js"></script
```